# Create additional workspaces in gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, workspaces

I can't seem to create additional workspaces in Gnome-shell. Compiz says I should have four (2 by 2) but I only seem to have 2 set up. So, how do I create additional workspaces in gnome-shell?

Comment: To clarify, what shell are you using on top of GNOME 3? Are you using Unity, GNOME Shell, GNOME Classic, etc.?

Comment: @WarriorIng64 Betcha its GNOME Shell.

Comment: Gnome shell. The idea was to drop Unity, which I still hate three months in. But my login option just says "gnome"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, gnome shell doesn't use compiz, it uses mutter.

Second, gnome shell has something that I've dubbed "auto workspace maker" - that is, as you fill up one workspace, gnome creates another for you. So if you put a window in your first workspace *and* your second, gnome will make you a third workspace and so on and so forth.

Comment: that would explain why changing my compiz settings had no effect.

Comment: Dynamic workspaces :-).

Comment: Huh. So does that mean I can't control how they stack?

Comment: Seems there are some tweaks available to break dynamic workspaces. I'll give them a try. http://piecesoflint.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/how-to-tweak-gnome-3-to-your-needs/

Comment: @Amanda I hope it works for you, but I'll warn you now that I didn't have much success with it when I tried it.

Comment: @jrg I actually moved to GNOME Openbox

Answer (score 3):

Try Workspace Grid, a [Gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/). It supports both up-down and left-right workspace navigation.